# Numbers.app force me to download Chinese fonts but the download always fails

Tags: macos, numbers, font

Whenever I open the Numbers app the pop up always shows up, requiring me to download Chinese fonts.

[image]

The dialog reads "Numbers.app needs to download the font. The size is 50MB.". However, when I click the download button, the download always fails, the progress bar showing up yet immediately disappearing.

The pop up dialog shows 8 times whenever I open the app, as it seems that there are 8 different fonts necessary for the download. The only solution so far is clicking the "Skip" button on the pop up for all the pop ups, which is very tedious.

I restarted my Mac and also deleted and re-installed the Numbers app but it did not pan out.

Is there any way to prevent the dialog from opening whenever I use the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem comes from the failure of download on Fontbook.app. Following [this question and answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/377914/cannot-download-fonts-on-fontbook-in-catalina/), I finally downloaded the font successfully and the popups no longer show up in opening the app.

---

#### Solution

Go to `System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Fonts/Subsets/` and download it directly.