# Cannot download fonts on Fontbook In Catalina

Tags: macos, font, font-book

I would like to download fonts on Fontbook app that is preinstalled on the system.

However, when I choose a font that is grayed-out on the list and click the download button, the download does not work. The download progress window shows up but is gone immediately, and the download always fails.

The font I want to download is 圆体-简. The Fontbook app cannot be re-installed. The download has not been working for months...

How can I make the download work properly?

---

I tried downloading other fonts that are not installed yet (fonts that are grayed-out), such as Gotu or Myriad Arabic. The download worked properly. Only Chinese fonts (手札体 and 圆体) fail.

Comment: are there any errors in console ? also look for firewall, both native and third party

Comment: @ankii There seems no error in console.app. Also I tried disabling the firewall and downloading it, but it didn't work...

Comment: @TomGewecke Catalina 10.15.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to install it from

> System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Fonts/Subsets/

The filenames are *Yuanti.ttc* for 圆体 and *Hannotate.ttc* for 手札体.